# PHP library similar to REST-driver in Java

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I found this [little library](https://github.com/rest-driver/rest-driver/wiki/Client-driver) to be perfect solution for my problem. It allows you to stub REST service responses easily. 
Now i need to replicate the same set of test cases in PHP version of our library. Do you know any similar library/framework in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/). Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client & framework for building RESTful web service clients. The thing is that you can create Response objects. In this library, you have a [Response class](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Response.php). You could just create the Guzzle Response that you want (choosing the desired status code, content, etc), and mock your HTTP Client so it returns the Response object that you just created.

If you read the documentation, it seems that there is [a plugin to mock responses](http://guzzlephp.org/guide/service/testing_clients.html#queueing-mock-responses), although I've never used it.